# How do I add lines to list as single string items?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to add lines of text to a list. I have the following code:

```
theText = 'foo \n bar'
for line in theText:
    theList.append(line)
print theList
```

This code prints:

```
['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', '\n', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

when I was expecting something more like:

```
['foo ', '\n bar']
```

Is there some way to get the entire line to be a single string item in the list?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful replies. It seems I was misunderstanding the use of `line` in my code to be a python keyword for a line in the supplied string. I saw this usage in other examples online and misunderstood. Apparently, I could have used any arbitrary word there, and it would refer to individual characters in the string. With this knowledge, the `split` recommendations below solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the lines and to keep the delimiters use splitlines with `keepends=True`, the correct result is   `['foo \n', ' bar']` as the newline is on the line with foo not bar :

```
theText = 'foo \n bar'
print(theText.splitlines(True))
['foo \n', ' bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your string by newlines. Otherwise it reads through each character in the string. `re.split` will retain the delimiters if you hold it in a capture group:

```
import re
...
for line in re.split( '(\n)',theText ):
    theList.append(line)
```

However, this will put the newline in a separate item, like this:

```
['foo ','\n',' bar']
```

[jaheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27554421/4329645) suggests using `re.findall`, which would give you the output you expect:

```
for line in re.findall( '(\n?.+)',theText ):
    theList.append(line)
```

Or, if you want to exclude the delimiter, you can completely ignore regex and just use `str.split`:

```
for line in theText.split('\n'):
    theList.append(line)
```

Comment: @AdamSmith `partition` only splits the string once. A larger string would return `['foo ','\n',' bar \n baz']`.

Comment: I assumed he wanted to do more with it than just put it on a list, but you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
re.findall('(\n?.+)', theText)
```

Edit:

Just to clarify the behavior of the loop. If you iterate over a string (i.e. `for char in string`) you get the string character by character. This is consistent with the index of each char (`char_0 = string[0]`, `char_1 = sring[1]`, ...). In contrast file-objects behave different. An iteration over a file-descriptor yields the lines of the file. So if your text was a file instead which contains the text you would achieve the expected result.

Comment: @DavidReeve hmmm so it does. I forgot that `.` doesn't match the newline except in `re.S` mode.

Comment: I still maintain that it's incredibly overkill to use regex in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you require that output, try this:

```
result = [word if i==0 else "\n" + word for 
              i,word in enumerate(theText.splitlines())]
```

`enumerate` pairs up the results of its argument with numbers, e.g.:

```
enumerate("abcd") == [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')] # roughly
```

So we're saying to split `theText` on newline, and give us the word itself if it's the first word in the sentence, otherwise add `"\n"` to the front of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, using purely python and no libraries is:

```
theText = theText.split('\n')
['\n'+theText[i] if i%2==1 else theText[i] for i in range(len(theText))]
```

Which yields the desired output:

```
>>> theText = theText.split('\n')
>>> ['\n'+theText[i] if i%2==1 else theText[i] for i in range(len(theText))]
['foo ', '\n bar']
>>>
```

**Step by step:**

```
>>> theText = 'foo \n bar'
>>> theText = theText.split('\n')
>>> theText
['foo ', ' bar']
>>> [theText[i] for i in range(len(theText)) if i%2==1]
[' bar']
>>> ['\n'+theText[i] for i in range(len(theText)) if i%2==1]
['\n bar']
>>> ['\n'+theText[i] if i%2==1 else theText[i] for i in range(len(theText))]
['foo ', '\n bar']
>>>
```

Comment: This only works if the intended result of `"foo \n bar \n baz"` is `["foo ", "\n bar", " baz"]` instead of `["foo ", "\n bar", "\n baz"]`. In the latter case -- my answer is pure python and produces that result. Frankly I don't know why OP is preserving whitespace and newlines!!! :)